# Django: Messages not being displayed

Tags: django, django-messages

I have following function for bulk operation of the selected rows in a ListView.
I am showing messages for success and error.

```
def archive_stores(view, queryset):
    if queryset.exists():
        queryset.update(archive=True)
        success_message = messages.success(view.request, 'Archived successfully.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stores_list', success_message))
    else: #The message is not shown when queryset of empty.
        error_message = messages.error(view.request, 'No success!.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('stores_list', error_message))
```

The success message is being displayed correctly. But the Error message never appears. Please guide me what can be the reason?

Following is the ListView:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class StoresListView(ActionViewMixin,ListFilteredMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'stores_listing.html'
    model = Store
    filter_set = StoreFilter
    actions = [archive_stores, unarchive_stores, delete_stores, export_stores,]
    paginate_by = 25
```

Following is the messages template:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{ message | safe }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the views?

Comment: Updated the question with a view. Pleas note I am using: django_actions package for generating admin like actions in the ListView.

Comment: Sry, I mean, templates *

Comment: Which part of the template you want me to post, only the template which is meant for showing messages or everything?

Comment: Only the part that show the messages

Comment: I fixed it by making changes in the django_actions package. I made changes in the view.py of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   def archive_stores(view, queryset):
      if queryset:
        queryset.update(archive=True)
        success_message = messages.success(view.request, 'Archived successfully.')
        return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stores_list', success_message))
      else: #The message is not shown when queryset of empty.
         error_message = messages.error(view.request, 'No success!.')
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('stores_list', error_message))
```

And I think you dont have to explicitly pass the message as a kwarg in reverse, since calling message.success() or message.error() alone will include the required message. You can update your view like this:

```
   def archive_stores(view, queryset):
      if queryset:
        queryset.update(archive=True)
        messages.success(view.request, 'Archived successfully.')
        return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stores_list'))
      else: #The message is not shown when queryset of empty.
         messages.error(view.request, 'No success!.')
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('stores_list'))
```

Comment: I have tried this. I don't know why the the Message in the else part never executes.

Comment: Have tried printing the queryset to make sure its empty?

Comment: I have tried printing to the console using :print('I am in else') print(queryset). Nothing is getting printed. I guess it ever enters the else part.

Comment: Try printing the queryset in the if part when it is expected to be empty.

Comment: Yes. even in the if part it does not print anything.